# Firebase: There was an error while loading /apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?authuser=1&project=enduring-sign-274118. Please try again

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, firebase-authentication

[image]

Hello, I am facing an error while enabling Authenticate with Firebase on Android using a Phone Number, Does anyone know how to solve this?
this is the full error text:

```
There was an error while loading /apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?authuser=1&project=enduring-sign-274118. Please try again.

Request ID: 10375038218392837291
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't  remember exactly, but i think the error is gone after a lot of refreshing and restart chrome process